# Не работают модули с discord api

Tags: python, discord-api

Вообщем суть в том, что я имею такой код:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
import isyouhere

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    elif ('тут?' in message.content):
        isyouhere.msg(message)
```

и соответственно модуль isyouhere:

```
def msg(message):
    print('[command]: here')
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Я тут!')
```

Итого, когда я пишу команду "тут?" он не пишет ни в дискорд, ни в консоли тоже нет текста об использовании команды. Help, please

P.S Подключение к дискорду выполняется, токен исправен, всё это трижды проверено

UPD. Исправил на то как ДОЛЖНО быть, проблему решил
UPD2. Не, не решил. Воткнулся в SyntaxError. По идее нужно делать кольцевые модули

Answer (score 0):

что за elif? у вас проблемы с синтаксом...просто if

```
async def on_message(message):
    if ('тут?' in message.content):
        isyouhere.msg(message)
```

Comment: Забыл в вопросе упомянуть. У меня иф - елиф в коде, это просто строчка вырванная со средины кода и модуль к ней. Соответственно с иф тоже не работает